# Can't make update two boards with other id, MongoDB, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I trying to make two updates, till this moment I do this, Could somoene correct this code or explain me how can I make two updates with using only one query??

```
Board.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: transferObj.idBoard },
    {
        $set: {
            ['lists.' + transferObj.fromIndexList + '.cards']: transferObj.fromCards,
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    },
    Board.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: transferObj.toBoard },
        {
            $set: {
                ['lists.' + transferObj.toList + '.cards']: transferObj.toCards,
            }
        },
        {
            upsert: true
        },
        ((err, updated) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
            else { res.status(200).send('Deleted'); }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works?

```
Board.bulkWrite(
    [
        {
            updateOne: {
                filter: { _id: transferObj.idBoard },
                update: {
                    ['lists.' + transferObj.fromIndexList + '.cards']: transferObj.fromCards
                }
            }
        },
        {
            updateOne: {
                filter: { _id: transferObj.toBoard },
                update: {
                    ['lists.' + transferObj.toList + '.cards']: transferObj.toCards
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: this two boards have other ID